# GLTF file not coming in three.js in Angular

Tags: angular, three.js

I want to **implement 3d model** of format **.gltf** in **threejs for Angular**.i **added the url** of sample .gltf format which i needed.**but the model is not coming**.I have adde the code for the refrence.Please help me to clear this issue.

code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-threejs-demo-basic-xbqcgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Look at your `package.json` file, you're using `"three": "0.106.2"`. This version is pretty outdated, you might get better results if you use the latest `three: 0.135`. I also suggest you look at your console for errors. I'm seeing an error with the gif header, which is unrelated to the GLTF.